# Is it possible to set ACLs on a sysfs mount point?

Tags: linux, acl

I'd like to add the write access on `/sys/power/state` to my UID via ACLs,
this way I'd don't need to use **sudo** or any setuid program to make my workstation go on sleepmode, is that possible ?
I tried, following the man, and add this error :

```
➜  ~  sudo setfacl -m u:nelson:w /sys/power/state
setfacl: /sys/power/state: Invalid argument
```

It looks like what happened is not exactly what I meant,

Could someone enlighten me a little ? I don't understand why the `setfacl` command acted like it was writing something to the FIFO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an ACL on anything in `/sys` might not be possible. The `sysfs` filesystem was originally based on ramfs, which doesn't have support for extended ACL's.

I did an strace of the setfacl command, and just before the `setxattr` call which returns EINVAL, there is a `getxattr` call which gives the error that the operation is not supported:

```
getxattr("/sys/power/state", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fff4ab593c0, 132) = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
```