# Use /sys/class/gpio/ in Python without root permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I want to interact with the GPIO pins using the Python module [Ablib](https://github.com/tanzilli/ablib). And I want to do this without root permissions. How can I achieve this?

When I create an `ablib.Pin` instance the module opens `/sys/class/gpio/export` and writes the pin number to it. Initially this raises an IOErro:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/class/gpio/export'
```

This can be solved easily with `chmod`. Now when I create an `ablib.Pin` instance I get an IOError on a different file:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sys/class/gpio/pioC16/direction'
```

`ls -la` on `/sys/class/gpio` returns:

```
--w-------  1 my_user my_user 4096 Jan  1 01:42 export
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  1 01:42 pioC16 -> ../../devices/ahb.0/apb.1/pinctrl.2/fffff800.gpio/gpio/pioC16
```

When writing 115 to `/sys/class/gpio/export`, the kernel creates the symbolic link `/sys/class/pioC16`. The problem it that `root` is owner of this link. I want that the new created files are owned by `my_user`. But I don't how to do this. I've tried `chmod` and `chown`:

```
$ chown -R my_user:my_user /sys/class/gpio
$ chmod g+s /sys/class/gpio
```

And I've tried `ACL`. But according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/747937/is-it-possible-to-set-acls-on-a-sysfs-mount-point) question it looks like I can't use ACL on a `sysfs`.

```
$ setfacl -m group:my_group:rwx /sys/class/gpio
setfacl: /sys/class/gpio: Invalid argument
```

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940526/247542).

Essentially, edit the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules` and append:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/gpio; chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/virtual/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/virtual/gpio'"
```

Then add your user to the "gpio" group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G gpio <youruser>
```

After rebooting, you should be able to read and write to /sys/class/gpio as a normal user. I just did this myself and it worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

The permission of the link is not so important...

the permission of the target is !!

please do a ls -la on "../../devices/ahb.0/apb.1/pinctrl.2/fffff800.gpio/gpio/pioC16"

Comment: This is not a answer, but a comment.